# Kali linux fail to boot after apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: apt, kali-linux, dist-upgrade

After running

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

command on my kali linux rolling edition, the OS fails to boot everytime and stuck at this messages.

```
loading, please wait...
'disk/by-uuid/1aacd4f4-do73-4e39-b456-fc7d3f78662c": invaild path for logical volume.
fsck from util-linux 2.29.1
/dev/sda1: clean, 3 74044/30015488 files, 4391943/120057088 blocks
[ 9.507788] kvm: disabled by bios
[ 9.550513] kvm: disabled by bios
[ 9.598133] kvm: disabled by bios
[ 9.636218] kvm: disabled by bios
[FAILED] failed to start Open Vulnerability Assessment System Scanner Daemon. see 'systemct1 status openvas-scanner.service' for details.
[OK] started WPA supplicant.
[FAILED] Failed to start Open Vulnerability Assessment System Manager Daemon. see 'systemct1 startus openvas-manager.service' for details.
[OK] Reached target Multi-User System.
[OK] Reached target Graphical Interface.
     Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
[OK] Started Update UTMP about System Renlevel Changes.
```

I noticed some changes at the grub menu: the wallpaper disappeared (Kali logo)

I tried booting in recovery mode running

```
apt-get clean && apt-get update
```

but that fails with some error messages, any help?

Comment: Without the error messages noone is going to be able to help

Comment: What do you see if you run `systemctl status openvas-scanner.service` like the boot log suggests?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. that means kali linux have some missing or damaged files.

```
  sudo apt-get upgrade
```

if this does not solve

```
  sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score -2):

I had to run

```
Xorg -configure
```

and move `xorg.conf.new` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

The problem was no `xorg.conf` existed at all. This worked after trying many things

Comment: Are you using a different account to answer? Or are you answering with the first person narrative?

Comment: How does this relate to the failure to start the "Open Vulnerability Assessment System Scanner Daemon"?

Comment: This does not seem related to the actual question in any way, shape or form.